# Prestashop 1.7 product combination price with TAXes

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm making combinations' table on product page and I am looping through it making table out of this in short:

```
{foreach from=$combinations key=comboid item=combination}
    {$combination.attributes_values.4|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
    {$combination.price}
{/foreach}
```

but the price it's showing is without taxes. Of course I also dumped $combination and there is only price without it, although in the backend I can provide price with taxes. I think there should be like some function "helper" to send the combination ID or product ID to and return price with taxes, but I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

P.S. I found the class called `CombinationDataProvider` in `/src/Adapter/CombinationDataProvider.php` which has a method `getFormCombination($combinationId)`. I think I could use it here somehow, because it returns such things as `final_price` of combination, but I can't figure out how to correctly do that. I tried to use it as a Tools class for ex. `{CombinationDataProvider::getFormCombination($comboid)}`, but the page stops rendering on the place, where I put this code.